# Pixels are off between gimp and chrome?

Tags: css, dimensions, gimp

I am using gimp designs to style my web pages. For some reason the dimensions are always off between chrome and gimp.

For example a div selected in gimp yields `200x450`.

If I enter:

```
.some_div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 450px;
}
```

The div that shows up in chrome is always smaller.

Can I enable some feature in gimp to make the exact?

Comment: Is there a margin, padding, and/or border that you're forgetting to mention?

Comment: Yeah the border was making it appear larger that it actually was. This question can be deleted. :(

Answer (score 1):

The number of pixels of an image in GIMP **is exact**. I simply can't be "off by 1" - the file save plug-in, for example, would crash, if it got informed the wrong image size.

Now...pixels as defined for CSS are not that exact - so, it possible the browser is off due to some settings or preferences (like ZOOM) - anyway, post a screenshot along with your question - maybe someone can get a better clue of what is oging on there.

Have you tried simply using another browser to check this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Make a screenshot of your div in chrome and paste it into gimp, so you can get the exact size of it.